# Spring config not found

Tags: spring, configuration, applicationcontext

I have the following in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have 2 files:

- applicationContext-web.xml in the WEB-INF next to the web.xml
- applicationContext-service.xml in the myapp-service.jar

When deploying the app, I get a

> No matching bean of type [AServiceBean] found for dependency: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this
>   dependency.

Seems like the applicationContext-service.xml is not found. If I copy it next to the web.xml, it works fine. I can't figure out why this happens.

The server is a Tomcat 6.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

For clarification: if I use

```
<param-value>
    classpath:applicationContext-web.xml,
    classpath:applicationContext-service.xml
</param-value>
```

the app deploys without any issue, so it's just a matter of finding (or not finding) the applicationContext-service.xml

Comment: Do you have `component-scan` configured ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your config files into the classpath.

```
WEB-INF/classess  is the directory you need to place your configuration files
classpath:applicationContext-*.xml will then work
```

or sth similar to this to keep them in one place

```
WEB-INF/classes/spring   
classpath:spring/applicationContext-*.xml
```

applicationContext-service.xml : You dont need to copy this one if it is already in the jar file

---

Sample main-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd         
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


<import resource="classpath:spring/config1.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:spring/config2.xml" />
.
.
<import resource="classpath:spring/configN.xml" />


</beans>
```

Comment: You did not follow my question. The config files ARE in the classpath. And the one that's not found is exactly the -service one, that is in a JAR.

Comment: yes, my bad. Whereabouts the service xml is in your jar file? is it at the root of jar or in some directory?

Comment: It's in the root of the JAR. I saw in the Spring docs there could be problems with wildcards. In the end I will probably have to stick to a list of context files names instead of using wildcards, especially since this app has to be able to run on a lot of servers and versions.

Comment: You can import all the config files in one and pass that in the web.xml

Comment: see above, i have updated with some sample file importing other config files.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `classpath*:applicationContext-*.xml` (there is asterisk before the colon).

However it may not work, e.g. JBoss has problems, to make it work you need use some special class loader from jboss.

Also, there are some [problems using patterns](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-wildcards-in-path-other-stuff) in root.

Anyway I would recommend avoid patterns, better to make an `applicationContext.xml` with two explicit `import` statements.

Comment: Nope. classpath*... doesn't work. Tried on Tomcat 7 too. No luck.

Comment: Thanks. That's the conclusion I arrived to, too (avoiding wildcard characters). I'll look into the import idea - never used that before, maybe it's time to give it a try.